# Anyway to split files to diff folder?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have over 100,000 files in a folder name: A, all are picture files either jpeg, or jpg extension with random file names, like abc.jpg, xcc.jpg, bbb.jpeg

Is there any way to move the all the 100k files to folder in the following structure:

Any order of the images don't matter, just need 5000 pic in each folder under B

```
Folder B -> Folder 1 (5000 of the jpg files)
            Folder 2 (next 5000 of the jpg files) 
            .
            Folder n (last 5000 remaining of files)
```

Batch files or powershell doesn't matter as long run in windows or cmd, I just can't think of any way to spilt files to 5000 per folder.

Any help is appreciated... Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell to Split huge folder in multiple folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817034/powershell-to-split-huge-folder-in-multiple-folders)

Comment: Well, I would like you to be more specific. You tagged Powershell, batch-file and cmd. Which one do you want?

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach for your scenario would be to use `Select-Object` to create batches of files and a counter variable `$i` to create folder names corresponding to the batch number.

```
$i = 1
while (($files = Get-ChildItem *.jpg, *.jpeg).Count -gt 0) 
{
    $folderPath = ".\Folder $i"
    New-Item -Type Directory $folderPath
    $files | Select-Object -First 5000 | Move-Item -Destination $folderPath
    $i += 1
}
```

See the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817034/powershell-to-split-huge-folder-in-multiple-folders), that [@Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4905480/matthew) posted in the comments for several alternative ways to tackle this type of problem.

Note: I am assuming, that you do not already have subfolders with the name "Folder 1", "Folder 2", and so on...

Comment: thanks tested both yours and Just a learner, yours run faster for moving the files

Comment: @StevenPoon I benchmarked my code as well as Manuel Batsching's. It turns out my code is faster. See my updates.

Answer (score 0):

Below code assume there are folders `folder_a` and `folder_b`. Your images are in `folder_a` and the code will move these images to `folder_b\folder_1\...`, `folder_b\folder_2\...`, `folder_b\folder_3\...` etc. Change these directory names based on your actual requirement. Run it in `folder_a` and it will do the work.

```
$split_at = 5000
# First, create the directories to store the images
$image_count = Get-ChildItem -File | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
1..[math]::Ceiling($image_count/$split_at) | %{New-Item -Name "folder_$($_)" -ItemType Directory -Path "..\folder_b"}

# Then move the images in batch to the destination directories
$folder_n = 1
while(Test-Path .\*) {
    Get-ChildItem | select -First $split_at | Move-Item -Destination "..\folder_b\folder_$($folder_n)" -Force
    $folder_n++
}
```

#### Benchmarks

I benchmarked my code as well as Manuel Batsching's. It turns out that my code is faster. Below is the benchmarking code and the result. Here I created 2999 image files each round and move them from `folder_a` to `folder_b` (which is at the same level in the file system).

```
Remove-Item -Path ..\folder_b\* -Force -Recurse
1..2999 | %{New-Item -Name "item $_.jpg"}

Measure-Command {
    $split_at = 43
    # First, create the directories to store the images
    $image_count = Get-ChildItem -File | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
    1..[math]::Ceiling($image_count/$split_at) | %{New-Item -Name "folder_$($_)" -ItemType Directory -Path "..\folder_b"}

    # Then move the images in batch to the destination directories
    $folder_n = 1
    while(Test-Path .\*) {
        Get-ChildItem | select -First $split_at | Move-Item -Destination "..\folder_b\folder_$($folder_n)" -Force
        $folder_n++
    }
}

Remove-Item -Path ..\folder_b\* -Force -Recurse
1..2999 | %{New-Item -Name "item $_.jpg"}

Measure-Command {
    $i = 1
    while (($files = Get-ChildItem *.jpg, *.jpeg).Count -gt 0) 
    {
        $folderPath = "..\folder_b\folder_$($i)"
        New-Item -Type Directory $folderPath
        $files | Select-Object -First 43 | Move-Item -Destination $folderPath
        $i += 1
    }
}
```

Result (My code):

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 7
Milliseconds      : 632
Ticks             : 76323557
TotalDays         : 8.83374502314815E-05
TotalHours        : 0.00212009880555556
TotalMinutes      : 0.127205928333333
TotalSeconds      : 7.6323557
TotalMilliseconds : 7632.3557
```

Result (Manuel Batsching):

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 13
Milliseconds      : 961
Ticks             : 139616227
TotalDays         : 0.000161592855324074
TotalHours        : 0.00387822852777778
TotalMinutes      : 0.232693711666667
TotalSeconds      : 13.9616227
TotalMilliseconds : 13961.6227
```

Comment: hi change the folder name and its running now, think will take some times to move all files. thanks

Comment: unfortunately for the last folder it doesn't create the folder, instead just move the files and keep over-written the file as the folder name.

e.g: last folder 31, folder is not created but files will keep move over and name as folder 31 instead for the remaining files

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry to hear that. Did you have backups? I'll check the code later. I tested it yesterday for a small amount of files and it sees ok.

Comment: I did find an error in the code and I've corrected it.