# How to sort e.g. 200 folders into 8 parent folders of 25 subfolders each? (Windows 10)

Tags: powershell, sorting, directory-structure

I have 200 individual folders with 50 files inside each folder. I would like to sort these 200 individual folders into 8 parent folders of 25 subfolders each, whilst retaining all the files inside the subfolders.

Ideally, the naming structure of the parent folders should follow a sequential pattern based on a phrase (So e.g. "rvolkov Files 1", "rvolkov Files 2", etc).

I have tried to find powershell script for the above, but it seems to only work with files and not folders, so I haven't been able to utilise it ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817034/powershell-to-split-huge-folder-in-multiple-folders))

How can I do this in Windows 10? If it helps, the individual folders are named after barcodes, so the first few digits are the same.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could loop through it. If it is a one-time operation, you don't need to generalize. Use counters to respectively 8 and 25 to do the operation you want.
How do you want to decide what goes where? Alphabetical?

Comment: Also: 8 copy/paste operations are not that really hard, is there really a need for automation? Or has your example been generalized?

Comment: Thanks IT M. Yes the example is partly generalised, it's anything between 200 - 400 folders, and something that I have to do most days. Copy and Paste is definitely an option, but it would be great to have something more efficient.

Comment: I have no experience in coding at all, could you point me in the right direction re: doing a loop through?

Comment: If you really need to do this a lot, add it to function in a custom module. That improves the operational speed drastically ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I assume is your question, this is a possible solution:

```
# GeneralParameters
$dir         = "C:\yourdirhere"
$ParentDepth = 8
$FolderCount = 25

$dirs        = gci $dir -Directory
cd $dir         #Makes it easier to debug and read the code, not entirely necessary.
$SubCounter = 0

for ($ParentCounter=1;$ParentCounter -le $ParentDepth;$ParentCounter ++) {
    mkdir "Parent$ParentCounter"
    for ($i=1;$i -le $FolderCount; $i++) {
        Move-Item -Path $dirs[$SubCounter].FullName -Destination "Parent$ParentCounter"
        $SubCounter++
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for this! Looks like this almost does the job perfectly. Only issue is every time I run this code I get a couple of errors - (1) it sorts the files into 8 directories numbered 1 - 8, but it also creates 8 different empty directories with the name "Parent1, Parent2" etc. (2) also, I suspect this is related, in each of the non-empty parent folders, there is a folder missing, and instead the contents of the missing folder (the 50 files inside the original individual folder) are inside the parent folder. Any idea how to amend this? Thanks again!

Comment: (https://imgur.com/a/pocFJoG) In case this makes more sense. The second image is inside the first directory (1)

Comment: The command was not intended to re-run in the same directory, indeed.

Comment: The `mkdir "Parent$ParentCounter"` part in the code creates a directory called ParentX, depending on the index number (looping through 1 'till 8).

Comment: Ow! I've seen it now, edited it ;-)

Comment: Problem was that `-Destination` also creates a directory if it doesn't exist. In my test case I had directories called 1-200, so that was no issue :-)

Comment: If you want to filter out the Parent folders to re-run the script, you could also modify the line to `$dirs=gci $dir -Directory | ? {$_.Name -notlike "Parent*"}`. In that case everything will be redistributed in Parent1 through 8. Some logic should be added if you want to check the index nr.